# Replacing substring inside string not working? Java XML

Tags: java, regex, replace

All,

I am storing SQL queries as XML for my java application to improve maintainability.

Parts of my query require parameterisation, therefore I have created identifiers that I can use to replace with values when I create my query string.

e.g.

```
WHERE CB.callback_date &gt;= TO_DATE('$LASTDATE$','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND CB.callback_date &lt; TO_DATE('$FROMDATE$','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

I have a function in my application that will replace these substrings.

```
public static String xmlQueryPrep(String prep)
{

    //add dates to query
    prep.replace("'$LASTDATE$'", "'20/10/2013'");
    prep.replace("'$FROMDATE$'", "'18/10/2013'");
    prep.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">");
    return prep;    
}
```

For some reason it is replacing the ASCII codes for < and > but it is not replacing my markup

**Output**

```
WHERE CB.callback_date >= TO_DATE('$LASTDATE$','DD/MM/YYYY')
  AND CB.callback_date < TO_DATE('$FROMDATE$','DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Why is it not replacing correctly?

Comment: It looks like you're using string operations to build SQL. Are you aware just how poor an idea that really is? If you can use a parameterized prepared query or a (correctly-designed) named query instead, you'll avoid a lot of trouble! (Note that this is true ___independent of what language you use___ to prepare the query.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Strings` in Java are [immutables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html).

> An object is considered immutable if its state cannot change after it
>   is constructed

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you will see that each method that is applied to a String  to modify its content will return a new String.

You should do :

```
prep = prep.replace("'$LASTDATE$'", "'20/10/2013'");
prep = prep.replace("'$FROMDATE$'", "'18/10/2013'");
prep = prep.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">");
return prep;
```

Or even better ([method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)):

```
return prep.replace("'$LASTDATE$'", "'20/10/2013'")
           .replace("'$FROMDATE$'", "'18/10/2013'")
           .replace("&lt;", "<")
           .replace("&gt;", ">");
```

Comment: In other words, string.replace(.....) returns a **new string** in which the replace operation has taken place, the old string is unaffected

Comment: Why is C++ different then with regards to strings?

Comment: Java is based on C/C++, but is s new/different language. There are many differences - thus is just one.

Comment: @serupticious Java's StringBuilder works a lot more like strings in C and C++, but it's (directly) used a lot less frequently.